# SSL Certifcate Request s2003 DC CA DNS Name not Avaiable

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am trying to submit a request for an SSL certificate on a Domain Controller in order to enable LDAP SSL, and having no end of problems.

I am following the information provided at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;321051 & http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=ldap_over_ssl

Steps taken so far:

1. Create Servername.inf with the following information

   ;----------------- request.inf -----------------

   [Version]

   Signature="$Windows NT$

   [NewRequest]

   Subject = "CN=servername.domain.loc" ; replace with the FQDN of the DC 
   KeySpec = 1 
   KeyLength = 1024 
   ; Can be 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, or 16384. 
   ; Larger key sizes are more secure, but have 
   ; a greater impact on performance. 
   Exportable = TRUE 
   MachineKeySet = TRUE 
   SMIME = False 
   PrivateKeyArchive = FALSE 
   UserProtected = FALSE 
   UseExistingKeySet = FALSE 
   ProviderName = "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" 
   ProviderType = 12
   RequestType = PKCS10 
   KeyUsage = 0xa0

   [EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]

   OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 ; this is for Server Authentication

   ;-----------------------------------------------
2. Create Certificate request by running: **certreq -new Servername.inf Servername.req**
3. Attempt to submit Certificate request to CA by running: **certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate: DomainController" request.req**
4. At which point I get the following error:
   The DNS name is unavailable and cannot be added to the Subject Alternate Name. 
   0x8009480f (-2146875377)

Trouble shooting steps I have taken so far
1. Modify the Domain Controller Template to supply Subject Name in Request restart Certificate Service, include SAN in Request, same error.
2. Re-installed Certificate Services / IIS / Restarted machine countless times

Any help resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check in the Active Directory for servername.domain.loc's entry. Look at its properties, check its DNS name attribute. If it is empty, add the DNS name.

Comment: Hi There RainDoctor, I've checked the properties as asked and it does have a DNS name.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: http://www.techpository.com/?page_id=1364
You need to edit the template to use the request supplied subject name instead of building it from AD.

Here are the relevant steps that i followed:

> 1. Click start->run, then key in command mmc
> 2. Click File in the mmc console, then select Add/Remove Snap-in…
> 3. Click Add… buton in the Add/Remove Snap dialog
> 4. Select Certificate Templates, Click Add
> 5. Close the window in step 4) available standalone snap-in window.
> 6. You will see “Certificate Templates”, Click OK.
> 7. Find “Domain Controller Authentication” in “Console Root\Certificate Templates”
> 8. Double click “Domain Controller Authentication” to open it.
> 9. Select the “Subject Name” tab, then select “Supply in the request”, click Apply

After editing the template you need to remove and add it to the CA again.